# Can the Fourier transform of a compactly supported function wind around a point?

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $f \in C_c(\mathbb{R})$. That is, $f$ is  a continuous, compactly-supported function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$.  Its Fourier transform
$$ \hat f(s) = \int_\mathbb{R} e^{-its} f(t) \ dt.$$
is in $C_0(\mathbb{R})$. That is, $\hat f$ is a continuous function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ vanishing at $\pm \infty$ (it also admits an entire extension $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, basically because the above integral makes sense for $s \notin \mathbb{R}$).

Since $\hat f(\pm \infty) = 0$, we can think of $\hat f$ as a loop in the complex plane, based at zero. I am interested in knowing:

> Can $\hat f$ have winding number 1 around some point $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f$ be the "shark fin" function given by
$$ f(t) = \begin{cases}
1-t^2 & \text{ if } t \in [-1,0] \\
(t-1)^2 & \text{ if } t \in [0,1] \\
0 & \text{ otherwise } 
\end{cases} $$

Here's a [plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20Piecewise%5B%7B%7B0,t%3C-1%7D,%7B1-t%2a%2a2,-1%3C=t%3C0%7D,%7B%281-t%29%2a%2a2,0%3C=t%3C1%7D,%7B0,t%3E0%7D%7D%5D).

It's Fourier transform (Wolfram Alpha uses $\hat f(s) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{s \pi}} \int e^{-its} f(t) \ dt$) is 
$$ \hat f(s) = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi}}  \frac{e^{-i s} (-1+e^{i s}) (s+i e^{i s}-i)}{s^3} $$

Here's a [parametric plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%28x=Re%28%28sqrt%282/pi%29%20e%2a%2a%28-i%20t%29%20%28-1%2be%2a%2a%28i%20t%29%29%20%28t%2bi%20e%2a%2a%28i%20t%29-i%29%29/t%5E3%29,%20y=%20Im%28%28sqrt%282/pi%29%20e%2a%2a%28-i%20t%29%20%28-1%2be%2a%2a%28i%20t%29%29%20%28t%2bi%20e%2a%2a%28i%20t%29-i%29%29/t%2a%2a3%29%29%20from%20t=-15%20to%2015) of that.

It's pretty clear that $\hat f$ has winding number 1 around some points. I'm not sure how I got it into my head that this shouldn't happen. I don't think it's possible to get rid of the bad behaviour at the origin though.